# How do i browse from a webpage for a folder and display its content to the page?

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to create a page in which the user browses their computer for a folder and then selects the folder and its content is displayed to the webpage. Im newish to creating pages but id like to create a page in which you find a folder containing music or movies etc and you can then view them on the browser page.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to show folders' content from the users computer in your webpage (this is a privacy/security/safety concern), at most you show user-selected files that have been dropped into the page or uploaded using a `file` input. For that, have a look into the FileReader API https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Comment: Files only need to be selected, not uploaded.

Comment: I thought it would be possible as things like plex show content etc?

Answer (score 0):

If it's an online music player you cannot access the user's files [because of security reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript#Security), unless the user decides to upload it's entire music collection to your server (I assume you don't want this).

If what you want is a "webpage" that runs locally and plays music, maybe you can use a framework like [AppJS](http://appjs.com/), which allows you to build applications using web technologies such as HTML5, JavaScript, etc.

Comment: An explanation for the downvote would be appreciated, thanks!